# How to load image from Mongo with the help of image path (with Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I need to show image from db. I stored the image path into db. My db is MongoDB, but I am not able to show the image in frontend, I get this error in console:

> Not allowed to load local resource:file path

How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: `<img ng-src="{{link}}"/> ` tried this?

Comment: hi @Rakeschand iam also using this only

Comment: what us the problem then ? can you share more details

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource still its come image not load

Comment: image look like this

Comment: does this image link works when you copy paste it in a browser tab. What does it shows, try --

Comment: yes @Rakeschand  its works image will show

Comment: will ? did you try it or not ?

Comment: ya already i try its image open in new tab help how to solve@Rakeschand

Comment: than I don't know man, only option right now is create a plnkr or jsfiddle I'll see there.